# How to convert the following output into an object?

Tags: powershell

```
Name                           Value                                                                         
----                           -----                                                                         
Server                         aaa1111                                                  
Printer                        bbb1111                                                         
Driver                         ccc1111                                                 
Port                           ddd1111                                               
Share                          eee1111
Server                         aaa2224                                                  
Printer                        bxb1111                                                         
Driver                         cccfff1                                                 
Port                           ddd1ggg                                               
Share                          
Server                         aaa2224                                                  
Printer                        bxb1111                                                         
Driver                                                                          
Port                           ddd1ggg                                               
Share                          shhhhhh



Name                           Value                                                                         
----                           -----                                                                         
Server                         aaa1111                                                  
Printer                        bbb1111                                                         
Driver                         ccc1111                                                 
Port                           ddd1111                                               
Share                          eee1111
Server                         aaa2224                                                  
Printer                        bxb1111                                                         
Driver                         cccfff1                                                 
Port                           ddd1ggg                                               
Share                          
Server                         aaa2224                                                  
Printer                        bxb1111                                                         
Driver                                                                          
Port                           ddd1ggg                                               
Share                          shhhhhh
```

I want to convert the above format of output into a custom object such that i can perform the below command.(some of the entries are empty for **Share** and **Driver** for which empty string should be there)

```
$object | Select-Object Server,Printer,Driver,Port,Share
```

The output is coming from a background job inside for loop like

```
foreach ( $key in $hash.key ) {
backgroundjob
}
```

each background jobs has output with name and value columns i want everything to be in a single object.

Comment: Where is the output comming from?

Comment: from a background job inside my script

Comment: Would help to see the script. It's easier to change the script, then to convert the output

Comment: you can see [here](http://codepad.org/jlbN73bc) variable `$($EachServerOutputHash[$key])` contains the output

Answer (score 2):

You return a `hashtable`, but want a `PSCustomObject`.

Find your hashtable

```
@{
    Server = 'aaa1111'
    Printer = 'bbb111'
    Port = 'ccc111'
}
```

and typecast it to a `PSCustomObject`, like this

```
[PSCustomObject]@{
    Server = 'aaa1111'
    Printer = 'bbb111'
    Port = 'ccc111'
}
```

Your script is hard to read, but I think you have to change line 65 to

```
[PSCustomObject]$arg5
```